# Is this code a correct implementation of Bubble Sort?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am used following bubble sort algorithm for making sorting . 
Is this algorithm correct?

```
for (int a = itemWiseBidderList.size() - 1; a > 1; a--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    { 
        if ((itemWiseBidderList.get(j).getRankInInt()) > (itemWiseBidderList.get(j + 1).getRankInInt()))
        {
           Collections.swap(itemWiseBidderList, j, j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try and lookup a standard bubble sort and see if it is correct?

Comment: Did you test the code? Did it sort the itemWiseBidderList as you expected? If so, the algorithm is correct, otherwise it's faulty. In the latter case tell us what the output is and we will help you. If it's the first case, you just waste our time ;)

Comment: What does it do when you test it?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as it is not correct to use Bubblesort at all. Use the sort method that comes with your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bubble sorting is not a requirement (by homework?), then the correct way to implement sorting in Java is by calling

```
Collections.sort(itemWiseBidderList);
```

If your list items implement `Comparable`, or

```
Collections.sort(itemWiseBidderList, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // Compare o1, o2 .getRankInInt() here
    }
});
```

This will be a lot faster than bubble sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo-code, you can verify if your code is correct:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
  n = length(A)
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     /* back through the area bringing smallest remaining element to position i */
     for (j = n-1; j > i; j--)
        if A[j-1] > A[j] then
           swap(A[j-1], A[j])
        end if
     end for
  end for
end procedure
```

source from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be correct (though I did NOT test it), however `Collection` is supposed to be comparable so you should probably just call `itemWiseBidderList.sort()`.

What datatype is `itemWiseBidderList`?

Comment: `Collection` does not have a `sort()` method. Some collections cannot be sorted (e.g. `Set`). But there's a utility method in `Collections`