# Is my Bubble Sort implementation correct?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
public class MyBubbleSort {

public static void bubbleSort(int[] a, int n)   {

    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 0; i <= (n-2); i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= (n-1); j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[i])    {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It gives me a sorted array when I do a debug but I just wanted to be 100% sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this code a correct implementation of Bubble Sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619722/is-this-code-a-correct-implementation-of-bubble-sort)

Comment: The `n` parameter is odd. Was that given?

Comment: Do you suppose that is unnecessary?

Comment: The `n` parameter could be replaced with `a.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could tidy the code a bit:

1. Make it extend an interface Sort with a single method `sort(int[] a, int n)`.
2. MyBubbleSort method should implement said interface and not be static.
3. `int i` and `j` should be declared inside the corresponding `for`declaration.
4. `temp` should be declared inside the inner `if`.
5. It is questionable if you need to pass in the length of the array as this is a property on the Java array type.  The only time to pass the length would be if you intended to sort sub arrays.

Comment: When I ran a Main method in debug mode it gave me a sorted array, but I just wanted to make sure it was sorted via bubble sort and not another way coincidentally.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a correct bubble sort ! In your "if" statement, you are correctly swapping two adjacent values if they are not well sorted. And this is the principle of the bubble sort: you repeat this process until your array is correctly sorted. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4

However you are doing strange things in your code ! As zapl said in the comments you don't need this "n" parameter as you can simply get you array's size in your method.

Also prefer using " < length ", " < length - 1 " instead of your <= which are, if you think well, more intuitive

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] tab)   {
        int n = tab.length ; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n ; j++) {
                if (tab[j] < tab[i])    {
                    int temp = tab[i];
                    tab[i] = tab[j];
                    tab[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```